# CentOS grub.conf template?

Tags: centos, grub

I want to add some parameters to the kernel line in grub.conf, but I want to make sure that when the kernel is updated that those parameters persist. How is the format determined? Is there a template that I can edit rather than having to remember to edit grub.conf after the fact?

Comment: I thought Kernel parameters are copied from the currently running Kernel to the new Grub entry on update. Is this not the behavior you are observing?

Comment: I haven't exactly observed anything yet, but I remember this being a thing a couple jobs ago when I was in a Debian environment, but I didn't see anything familiar in `/boot/grub`. I suppose I'll take your word for it and see what happens the next time my kernels get updated.

Comment: Yea, I think in Debian there's a grub.cfg file.